# How to get path of selected image

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

Currently i am taking image from `camera and gallery` . When i take picture from camera then the path is `storage/sdcard0/pictures/androidfileupload/`.

```
 private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "Android File Upload");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }  else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

so from the above code i am fetching `storage/sdcard0/pictures/android file upload/` .

Now i am taking selected image from gallery so it shows error like `storage/sdcard0/pictures/androidfileupload/imagename.jpg` is not found .

I have debug the code and i get the path of selected image from gallery `content://media/external/images/media/26435` but i want the path like 
`content://media/external/images/media/imagename.jpg`.

so how can i get the path with `imagename.jpg`.?